# Why didn't I receive the Knowledgeable badge?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation, badges

The description for the [Knowledgeable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5853/knowledgeable) badge is

> First proposed change to be approved by others that handles others'
>   improvement requests

I submitted a proposed change on an improvement request and it was approved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/94592) However, I have not received the badge... Can anyone explain why? The changes are published on [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/coldfusion/4904/variables/17307/checking-if-a-variable-exists#t=20160912180520560091). What am I missing?

Comment: You're the one that originally created that example. The system might ignore subsequent edits you make in that case. Not sure why the badge would be set up that way though.

Comment: It wasn't my improvement request though... Wouldn't SO want people to meet others' improvement requests? Otherwise why bother to edit it?